# Blue/Green Deployment for AWS API-Gateway using codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-codepipeline

I know codepipeline has an option for Blue/Green deployment onto ECS cluster, I have a few API's that are hosted on API-Gateway that talks to ECS cluster ALB/NLB. Is there a way that I can test my new version API's similar ECS before I delete the older version of API hosted on the API-Gateway?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what you can use stages in API Gateway for a blue stage and a green stage [Blue/Green Medium](https://medium.com/@ben11kehoe/enabling-blue-green-deployments-and-split-testing-on-api-gateway-a-modest-proposal-2f3b6f2f7e1c) is a great example of that. There is also [Canary Testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/canary-release.html) which has come out a bit later.

Comment: Appreciate it @david, can you please share the link again? Looks like hyper link is not working